# Why is my session variable not passing correctly?

Tags: php, variables, single-sign-on, session-variables

```
function User_CustomValidate(&$usr) {
    $appKey = "xxxxx";
    $safeurl =  'https://safe.xxxx.com/login/sso/SSOService?app=playbooks';

    // first call back after safe login - POST is set
    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['digest'])) 
    {
     $digest = $_POST["digest"];

     // set the session variables ...
     $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"];
     $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST["firstname"];
     $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST["lastname"];
     $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST["email"];
     $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST["uid"];


     // Needed for key
     $uid = $_POST["uid"];
     $time = $_POST["time"];

     // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code ...
     // this sets $appKey and $safeurl

     $mykey = "".$uid.$time.$appKey;
     $mydigest = md5($mykey);
    }

    // session is not initialized as we never got the post above to set session vars
    // call now the safe login to get the post to set the session vars ...

    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || empty($_SESSION['uid']))
    {

     // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code ...
     // this sets $appKey and $safeurl

     header("Location: ".$safeurl);
    }


    $usr = $_SESSION['uid'];        
    $this->setCurrentUserName($usr);
            return TRUE;   

    }
```

I am creating a SSO function that is supposed to carry over the SSO digest data to my applications.  I am having an issue with a variable that I cannot figure out.  All of my SESSION variables are working and I can clearly see their results on all of my pages.  So when I echo $_SESSION['uid'] I can see whatever uid that is passed from our SSO.  But I am getting nothing from $usr.  I have the statement $usr = $_SESSION['uid'] and it returns nothing.  However when I set $usr to '888888' it returns that static uid and everything works.  How can I get the session uid passed right?

Comment: as per usual... did you call session_start() in the scripts where you're accessing session data, and make that call BEFORE any output has been performed?

Comment: What is the ampersand in the function?

Comment: Yes - if (session_id() == "") session_start(); // Initialize Session data
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering -

Comment: @LiamSorsby pass var by reference

Comment: `$_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST["uid"];` and `$uid = $_POST["uid"];` does the same thing.

Comment: The POST data is used to authenticate with the SSO application key.  The only thing I really need for my application is $_SESSION['uid'] since I have a lookup table of all employees and just match uid with employee id.  I just need to populate $usr to do this.

Comment: $uid and none of the $POST variables pass either.

Comment: I stripped my page except for the above code and ech statements to make sure there wasn't any interference...  I am getting a return for $_SESSION['uid'] but nothing for $usr.  $usr gets error - Notice: Undefined variable: usr.  HELP!!! haha

Comment: can you post the code that calls `User_CustomValidate()`? as well as the setCurrentUserName? Also, what line do you get the error of the undefined variable?